# React - property of undefined while rendering data from Mongo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined-behavior, mern

Ok, I'm done fighting for today. Please help. Trying to write my first app. I decided to use MERN stack and I'm having problems connecting frontend and backend.
Backend is working fine, I receive data in Postman.
Code and explanation below, please keep in mind that this is playground code I'm using to check problems solutions. Highest level of KISS to extract one issue.
Let's go, react code:

```
import React from 'react';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      arr:[] 
    }
  }
    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://localhost:4001/animals')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          var outputArr = Object.keys(data).map(key => {return data[key]})
          return outputArr
        })
        .then(data => {
          console.log('seting state: ')
          console.log(data)// first object is 'success' boolean, second is array of documents from mongo
          this.setState({ arr:data[1] })
        });     
    }

  render(){
    console.log('array in this.state: ')
    console.log(this.state.arr)
    //console.log(this.state.arr[1].name) - this is crashing code - TypeError

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>rendering App</p>
        <hr></hr>  
        <p>{/*this.state.arr[1].name*/}</p>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default App;
```

In console I see, that data are ok:

```
array in this.state:
[
  {
    "_id": "5eb6d1097726ef7946027fd6",
    "name": "Matylda",
    "type": "kot",
    "birth_date": "01.01.2010",
    "foto_path": "",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5eb6d1097726ef7946027fd7",
    "name": "Fuks",
    "type": "kot",
    "birth_date": "01.01.2008",
    "foto_path": "",
    "status": "active"
  }
//and so on...

]
```

But when I try to access particular dat (name for example, as in commented parts) I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".
Tried many different ways. If I add testing array of object as variable everything works fine. I feel in my bones it is something with this keys in objects from api, but I can't figure out what is wrong and how to make it work.

Comment: The problem is that your initial state has an empty array. You need some other content - such as a loader of some sort - to display before the API response arrives.

Comment: Please include the console output as text, not a picture. Pictures do not render well on some device, and some people may not be able to read your colour scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand your problem you need some understanding of [React lifecycle hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

You're fetching your data in the `componentDidMount` hook which runs *after* the `render`, when the component has already been mounted to the DOM.

So when your component is mounting the first time round `this.state.arr` is still just an empty array, you haven't yet set the data from your fetch in state.

If you instead initialise your state object as:

```js
this.state = {
  arr: null
}
```

...and then in your `render` before doing anything else put a condition like:

```js
render(){
  if (!this.state.arr) return <h1>Fetching Data...</h1>
  // The rest of your render here...
}
```

This should prevent your app from crashing the first time it tries to render the component before the data is fetched. And also provide a helpful message that the component is still waiting for the data from the API (You could replace the `h1` with a spinner component or some other loading state component).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @Gnommer You're most welcome! All the best with the rest of your app!

Answer (score 0):

Since this.state.arr is an object, you should be able to access the name field with this.state.arr.name instead of this.state.arr[1].name.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but this.state.arr is array of objects, so it wasn't the matter.

Answer (score 0):

try this.state.arr['0'].name... It might be possible that data could be an object and you may get them trought attributes names as strings, even if they look like numbers.

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Unfortunately no. There was problem with lifecycle hooks, answer from DexDeLoan helped. Still don't know why, but I'll try to understand.
Interesting is that after fixing it works with ['0'] as in your solution and without quotation marks [0].
Anyway, thanks for post!